# I need separated underscores

Tags: css, fonts

I would like to display a number of underscores to the user to let them know how many characters they need to fill in to satisfy the length requirement.

My problem is: underscores aren't separated by spaces.

Q: What font or css style should I use so that my underscores can be easily counted?

Comment: What about separating the underscores with &nbsp; ?

Comment: as an alternative suggestion, you could just have the field use a numeric counter and highlight green when the length is met.

Comment: css letter spacing is perfect for this. It would be the best way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use `letter-spacing: 0.4em;` to separate out the various characters in the element. I'm assuming you're using an `input` element, so:

```
input {
    letter-spacing: 0.4em; /* or whatever measurement you prefer... */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HT4Nz/).

References:

- [`letter-spacing` at the MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/letter-spacing).

Answer (score 6):

Use the CSS property [letter-spacing](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/letter-spacing).

Visual example: http://jsfiddle.net/8w9WY/